# React hook form + Yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Я пытаюсь добиться в своей схеме не совсем валидации, но сообщения для пользователя. Под полем input. У моей схемы есть следующие параметры:

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string()
      .required("Поле обязательно для заполнения")
      .max(50, "Заголовок не более 50 символов"),
  });
```

При этом в самом компоненте я получаю кол-во введенных символов:

```
{...register("title", {
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.value.length);
  }
})}
```

Моя задача выводить кол-во оставшихся символов под input пока пользователь не введет >=50 символов. При этом строго к валидации это не относится, т.к. это просто информативное поле. Могу ли я каким-то образом рассчитывать это значение в Yup? Буду благодарен вашим советам. Так как довольно сложно начинать с этой библиотекой!

Answer (score 0):

Я не сильно уверен, это ли вам нужно, но вы можете прописать [кастомный валидатор](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#field-level-validation):

```
function validateUsername(value) {
   let error;
   if (value === 'admin') {
     error = 'Nice try!';
   }
   return error;
 }

<Field name="username" validate={validateUsername} />
```

У вас полагаю это будет выглядеть как то так:

```
const someValidation = (value) => {
   let error

   if (value.length < 50) {
     error = `Осталось ${50 - value.length} символов`
   }

   return error
 }

<Field validate={someValidation} />
```

Comment: пользуясь инструментом валидации не хочется чего-то еще накручивать кастомного. К тому же это непосредственно к валидации относится

Comment: @elarri тогда я бы на вашем месте попробовал прокинуть колбэк в max, например .max((value) => console.log(value)), но это все догадка, с либой я плохо знаком, вскользь приходилось года 3 назад задеть, если таким образом получится, то можете применить валидатор, что я добавил выше.

Comment: валидатор для валидности, сдесь скорее useWatch() ну и span с текстом )

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что для ТС уже вряд ли актуально, но может пригодиться тем, кто ищет ответ на тот же вопрос:

Можно использовать функцию yup.**test()**
https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema

Вообще, функция довольно универсальная, и её можно использовать для самых разных проверок, в том числе с асинхронными вызовами.

Пример:

```
export const schema = yup.object({
  title: yup
    .string()
    .test('length', (value) => {
      // console.log('value:', JSON.stringify(value));
      const left = MAX_LENGTH - value.value.length;
      if (left >= 0) {
        return 'Осталось символов:' + (left);
      } else {
        return `Не более ${MAX_LENGTH} символов`;
      }
    }, () => {
      return false;
    })
    .max(MAX_LENGTH, 'Не более 50 символов')
    .required('Отсутствует значение'),
});
```

Но тут есть проблема: если возвращается false, то сообщение об ошибке выводится, но тогда и вся форма становится невалидной. Как при этом и выводить сообщение, и игнорировать ошибку при сабмите - непонятно.

Согласен с Armen, валидатор нужен для валидности, а здесь лучше использовать watch() и span с текстом.